# Import file path instead of a file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a <strike>pen</strike> .less file where i import css from a separate library and a font.

```
@import url('node_modules/some-library/style.css');
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf');
}
```

Is there a way not to import the font file? So in the compiled version there still will be just a path to this file (literally `src: url('../fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf')`). All i figured out is that webpack can either import font as bas64 or copy the font in the build folder and import it from there. Is there a way just to leave the font where it is and not copy it anywhere or transform it in any way? But the possibility of importing other css files should remain.

Thank you.

Comment: share your webpack config file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hLg1WUVb

Comment: Using url-loader or file-loader is not ideal in this case? You want it to just leave the string `'../fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf'` as is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IgnorePlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#ignoreplugin) to ignore the `require` call i.e. `url('../fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf');`.

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/Ubuntu-R\.tff/)
],
```

**Note**: You shoud have respective loader added into the loaders list for the font file type.

Or you can use [`ignore-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader) to ignore the files to be included with the bundle.

```
loaders: [
  { test: /\.tff$/, loader: 'ignore-loader' }
]
```

Comment: neither of those worked. ignore-loader just adds `src: url([object Object]);` to the output and the IgnorePlugin says that i need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.